# AngularJS - Define Data Models for Specific Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am 2 days new to AngularJS and covering online tutorials to learn more about this powerful framework. Yet one questions I still haven't found the answer to is how do I create a data structure that would handle specific transactions? E.g. for the user management controller, I would like to have a user data structure that has username, email, password, etc. so that I can create an instance of this structure and store data in it locally for transactions.

Any suggestions or help will be welcomed.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying tom implement static authentication system ?

Comment: With SPA apps, you retrieve the data once and it lives throughout the life of the app. You always have access to it

Comment: Not sure what static means but my authentication will be based on Parse backend

Comment: The only way to interact with the server in SPA is AJAX (or Websocket). Not sure if your question was about it.

Comment: The interaction mechanism is clear it's about how we store the data locally once retrieved from external DB. People over websites recommend using $scope variable array to store it. I want to know if there is a better way than scope.

Comment: @ksa_coder A $scope AFAIK is the only place a data could end up in. The only question is --- in which controller. You might want to have a separate controller to keep session data.

Comment: Oh thanks @vehsakul appreciate the clarification.